# CASE WHEN EXISTS in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, ddl, plsqldeveloper

I want to print all employee names and also if the employee is present in a table.

| EMP_ID | ENAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ALLEN |
| 2 | MAX |
| 3 | BEN |

| EMP_ID | EC_CODE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | CONFIG_1 |
| 2 | CONFIG_2 |
| 3 | CONFIG_1 |

Query:

```
SELECT 
    ename, 
    (CASE 
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM m_emp_config ec 
                      WHERE ec_code = 'CONFIG_1' AND emp_id = emp.emp_id) 
             THEN 'Y' 
             ELSE 'N' 
     END) config
FROM 
    emp emp
```

Can we write the `CASE WHEN EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause instead of there?

I am new to SQL, please help me.

Expected output for the SQL statement:

| ENAME | CONFIG |
| --- | --- |
| ALLEN | Y |
| MAX | N |
| BEN | Y |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current query is correct for doing this via exists.  Here is an alternative version using a left join:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    e.ENAME,
    CASE WHEN ec.EMP_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS CONFIG
FROM emp e
LEFT JOIN m_sys.m_emp_config ec
    ON ec.EMP_ID = e.EMP_ID AND
       ec.ec_code = 'CONFIG_1'
ORDER BY e.EMP_ID;
```

Comment: Only when there's a single row per employee in the config table. Otherwise it requires `distinct` or aggregation

Comment: You are right, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Using Decode statement

SELECT
em.ename,
DECODE(econ.ec_code,'Config_1', 'Y','N') AS config
FROM emp em
JOIN m_emp_config econ
ON econ.emp_id = em.emp_id
ORDER BY em.emp_id;

Using Case statement

SELECT
em.ename,
Case econ.ec_code when 'Config_1' then 'Y'
Else 'N' END AS config
FROM emp em
JOIN m_emp_config econ
ON econ.emp_id = em.emp_id
ORDER BY em.emp_id;

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `DECODE` instead of a `CASE WHEN` construct.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
e.ename, 
DECODE(ec.ec_code,NULL, 'N','Y') AS config
FROM emp e
LEFT JOIN m_emp_config ec
ON ec.emp_id = e.emp_id AND
ec.ec_code = 'Config_1'
ORDER BY e.emp_id;
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comment under my answer, you probably need a distinct select here.